# Using enum as FK on EF 6

Tags: entity-framework, enums, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6.1

I'd like to use an enum as Foreign Key in a Code-First app. Since enums are stored as int, I thought I could use the attribute [ForeignKey] on the enum property, but it throws this exception:

```
The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint 
must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role
```

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
public enum UserType
{
    Administrator = 1,
    Member = 2
}

public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TypeDetails")]
    public UserType Type { get; set;}

    public virtual MasterType TypeDetails { get; set; }
}

public class MasterType
{
    public int MasterTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to do this or something similar through fluent api or migrations?

Thanks

Comment: Shirley you want `public UserType MasterTypeId { get; set; }`

Comment: Right, what Aron said. The error message is telling you that `User.Type` and `MasterType.MasterTypeId` have different types.

Comment: Also...why not just use `DescriptionAttribute` on your enum?

Comment: Aron, I need to store more info than the description, thats why I use another table.

The problem is that MasterType stores information about other enums too, so I can use the enum type in the PK

Comment: hvd, I know that, but in the database the enum is stored as an int, so I thought that it may be a way to do this.

Comment: I could add another property to store the Id and add the [NotMapped] attribute to the enum type. Then I can add the assignments of the Id in the getter and setter of the enum property, but doing it this way ends up with one extra property for each enum...

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167665/ef5-code-first-enums-and-lookup-tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one I made earlier: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ef-enum-to-lookup

It's a nuget package that provides a method you can call in your `Seed` (initializer and/or migrations) which will automatically build lookup tables and add FKs where the enum is used. [Usage info](https://github.com/timabell/ef-enum-to-lookup/blob/master/ExampleUsage/EnumExample.cs).

Enjoy :-) And let me know if it works for you (or anyone else for that matter!)

Comment: Nice! I'll try it soon as I've been doing more ADO.NET than EF recently. Thanks!