# How to execute a T4 template to generate enums in Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, enums, t4

I have a project using `Entityframework Code First`. And the model contains a few enums which I want to generate from the database using the `T4` text template.

But I'm facing a few challenges:

- If the database doesn't exist yet, no enums will be generated;
- If the database does exists, how to run the `T4` template?
- And how do I get the enums in the database before running the `T4` template?

Has anyone done this before and overcome these challenges?

Comment: which version of Entity Framework are you using? EF 5 and later have built in support for enum data types without the need of T4.

Comment: I have the latest stable version, 6.1.2 IIRC. But what you said is true, but I need them as lookup tables in the database too.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/11167665/10245

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a NUGET package which handles the case that you are trying to solve, [ef-enum-to-lookup](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ef-enum-to-lookup).  [Documentation](https://github.com/timabell/ef-enum-to-lookup).

> Run  `EnumToLookup.Apply()` from your Seed method in either your database initializer or your EF Migrations.

This package creates lookup tables and foreign key constraints based on the `enums` used in your model.  Unlike the default Entity Framework support, you do not need to create a `DBSet<T>` for your `enum` classes, which maps `enum` values to `int`.

Comment: Damn that looks great! Does it handle a collection of enums too? I have looked at the sample project, I didn't see any collection of enums at all in an entity class.

Comment: in my experience, it handles any enum that is referenced by an entity object, either directly or through collections.  however, you will definitely want to verify the schema that gets generated.

Comment: Cheers for the recommendation @Claies :-)