# Convert string to enum value in FirstOrDefault?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a model with a property of type enum. In the database I want to store not the enum value number
and the value itself as a string. And when using EF Core FirstOrDefault I get the value from the database I want to convert the string to an enum.
I think it can be done with attributes but I don't understand how to do it. I hope I wrote clearly

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    value1,
    value2,
    value3
}   

public class MyClass
{
    public int Id;  
    public MyEnum myEnum; //in the database the string "value2". Now of course it's a mistake. Need to convert from string to enum value
}

var myClass = context.MyClases.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Id);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-c-sharp is this helpful?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Store enum names in database with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509273/store-enum-names-in-database-with-entity-framework)

Comment: You did not write clearly. "In the database I want to store not the enum value number and the value itself as a string" makes no sense. What do you want to store?

Comment: Please see the duplicate and the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations#configuring-a-value-converter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your DbContext override the `OnModelCreating`  and specify the following configuration.

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<MyClass>()
        .Property(e => e.myEnum)
        .HasConversion(
            v => v.ToString(),
            v => (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), v));
}
```

or

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<MyClass>()
        .Property(e => e.myEnum)
        .HaveConversion<StringToEnumConverter<MyEnum>>()
}
```

This will run a conversation for this property and what's stored in the databsae.