# What's $-operator supposed to mean for a string?

Tags: c#, string

So, I've just had the following conversation with a user in [the comments section](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34558339/1525840).

Me:

```
Year year = new Year{ State = States.Happy };
```

Them:

```
eventStream.ReceiveJoke += joke =>  
    Console.WriteLine($"Pretty nice joke: {joke}, Thanks!!!");
```

And, nerdy as I am, I wonder what he meant by the dollar sign but I think it's too embarrassing to ask him.

Comment: Konrad, there is no problem to ask me about it, I love help people :D

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro You were **not** supposed to see this. I wanted to get back to you with an even more witty comment. Darn... *year.State = States.Darn;*

Comment: I saw and already answered this question :P

Comment: I don't want to edit in case I've missed your reasoning, but I suggest asking what it *does* mean, not what it's supposed to mean :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop Good suggestion. However, I don't want to make changes because right now Skeety is displayed as a co-author and to us, low-pointers, it's like a badge (bronze, silver, gold, skeet), hehehe. Obviously, I won't rollback if you edit. Maybe you can ask Jon to edit? (Just kidding, just kidding.)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's an interpolated string literal, introduced in C# 6.

It's broadly equivalent to:

```
eventStream.ReceiveJoke += joke =>  
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Pretty nice joke: {0}, Thanks!!!", joke));
```

The compiler looks for braces within any string literal introduced with `$`, and applies string formatting to it. You can use (mostly) arbitrary expressions, rather than just variables, e.g.

```
Console.WriteLine($"{year.State} {2000 + 16}"); // Happy 2016
```

Comment: Why is it called interpolated?

Comment: Jon, I was under the impression that string interpolation produces the same IL as an equivalent `string.Format`. Is this false?

Comment: @Gusdor: It depends on what you do with it. Sometimes you use it as a `FormattableString` instead, so that you can format it later or do so in the invariant culture, for example. That's why I've put that it's "broadly" equivalent, to avoid overgeneralizing :)

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ what is a **YAB**?

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ What's YAB? (Also, I just realized that the abbreviation of JavaScript is ambiguous... Spooky... My initials only conform to "basement floor" and "department of corrections" in my language...)

Comment: @KonradViltersten: I suspect it's "yet another badge" in this context.

Comment: It's also in VB.NET 14.0 (the one with VS2015).

Answer (score 24):

It's the symbol that allow you to create a interpolated string, it's a new feature from C# 6, and I love it.

Also its a Syntax Sugar, I will explain what it mean in the end.

#### Lets see in action. look the following code

```
public string Receive(int value)
{
    return String.Format("Received: {0}", value);
}

public string Receive6(int value)
{
    return $"Received: {value}";
}
```

#### What happens what it is compiled

They will have the same IL implementation, look here the IL(in Debug mode, not optimized) from **Receive**

```
.method public hidebysig instance string Receive (int32 'value') cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x22d4
    // Code size 22 (0x16)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] string
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldstr "Received: {0}"
    IL_0006: ldarg.1
    IL_0007: box [mscorlib]System.Int32
    IL_000c: call string [mscorlib]System.String::Format(string, object)
    IL_0011: stloc.0
    IL_0012: br.s IL_0014

    IL_0014: ldloc.0
    IL_0015: ret
} // end of method Program::Receive
```

#### Now lets see IL(in Debug mode, not optimized) from **Receive6**

```
.method public hidebysig instance string Receive6 (int32 'value') cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x22f8
    // Code size 22 (0x16)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] string
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldstr "Received: {0}"
    IL_0006: ldarg.1
    IL_0007: box [mscorlib]System.Int32
    IL_000c: call string [mscorlib]System.String::Format(string, object)
    IL_0011: stloc.0
    IL_0012: br.s IL_0014

    IL_0014: ldloc.0
    IL_0015: ret
} // end of method Program::Receive6
```

As you can see with your own eyes, the IL is pretty much the same.

#### Now lets understand what is a Syntax Suggar

> In computer science, syntactic sugar is syntax within a programming language that is designed to make things easier to read or to express. It makes the language "sweeter" for human use: things can be expressed more clearly, more concisely, or in an alternative style that some may prefer.

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar

So instead to write the massive `string.Format`, use string interpolation, the compiler will work for you and convert the syntax that you wrote, in another code, in this case, using `string.Format`.

#### Can I use formatting options like in string.Format?

Yes, you can, look below

```
public static string Receive(int value) 
    => string.Format("Received: {0, 15:C}", value);

public static string Receive6(int value) 
    => $"Received: {value,15:C}";

Console.WriteLine(Receive(1));
Console.WriteLine(Receive6(1));
Console.WriteLine($"Current data: {DateTime.Now: MM/dd/yyyy}")
```

Output (my culture is pt-br)

```
Received:         R$ 1,00
Received:         R$ 1,00
Current data:  01/01/2016
```

**Obs.:** I would like to mention, there is not performance difference, since using string interpolation e string.Format is exactly the same thing

Answer (score 8):

In short, it is good way to improve the readability of the code and reduce its length. It's much better then `String.Concat` or + operator because string interpolation executes just one time as `String.Format` (and it is actually compile to `String.Format` method call) and you can just read the expression from left to right.

> `String.Format` and its cousins are very versatile and useful, but their use is a little clunky and error prone. Particularly unfortunate is the use of `{0}` etc. placeholders in the format string, which must line up with arguments supplied separately:
>
> ```
> var s = String.Format("{0} is {1} year{{s}} old", p.Name, p.Age);
> ```
>
> String interpolation lets you put the expressions right in their place, by having “holes” directly in the string literal:
>
> ```
> var s = $"{p.Name} is {p.Age} year{{s}} old";
> ```
>
> Just as with `String.Format`, optional alignment and format specifiers can be given:
>
> ```
> var s = $"{p.Name,20} is {p.Age:D3} year{{s}} old";
> ```
>
> The contents of the holes can be pretty much any expression, including even other strings:
>
> ```
> var s = $"{p.Name} is {p.Age} year{(p.Age == 1 ? "" : "s")} old";
> ```
>
> Notice that the conditional expression is parenthesized, so that the : "s" doesn’t get confused with a format specifier.

[Via](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6)

Comment: Please make it clear when you're quoting another post by using blockquotes, rather than just a link at the end of the post which doesn't make it really clear that you're simply quoting MSDN.

Comment: Why did you change my edit to make it unclear that the code in the answer was *also* just quoted from the Roslyn github page? It's simpler as it is, IMO.

Comment: Sorry it's just concurrency conflict. Also, you did the same with my first paragraph.

Comment: What is this `{{s}}` thing?

Comment: @Random832 since in string interpolation the { is a special character, if you want to write a { instead use it as special character, you must escape it, and the escape way is to add another {, this happens in string.Format also also.

Answer (score 5):

This is a new feature of C# 6 that is called string interpolation, which

> lets you more easily format strings. String.Format and its cousins are
>   very versatile, but their use is somewhat clunky and error prone.

For further information about this, please have a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/11/20/new-features-in-c-6.aspx).

**Example**

Let that we have the following class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

and let suppose that we want to ovveride the `ToString` method, like below:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("The customer with Id: {0} has as FirstName: {1} and as LastName: {2}", Id, FirstName,
            LastName);
}
```

In C# 6 we could have the same result using string interpolation.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"The customer with Id: {Id} has as FirstName: {FirstName} and as LastName: {LastName}";
}
```

Benefits of string interpolation:

- A string is significantly easier to read than a composite string.
- There is a reduction in the syntax errors caused by arguments following the format string that are in improper order, or missing altogether and causing an exception.