# Connecting to MySql 8 from ASP.NET Core 2 web app whithin docker-compose

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I'm trying to use a Docker compose script to connect to a MySql container from my ASP.NET Core 2.1 web app (hosting on Windows 10 Pro, all the containers using Linux), but I always an *Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts* error.

The app uses two services, a MongoDB container and a MySql container (using the latest Docker image with MySql 8). The API app waits for the MongoDB service using a bash script (https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it), and this seems to work.

As for MySql, googling around for a solution I added:

- `command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password` (https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/454)
- `MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%` (e.g. https://forums.docker.com/t/connect-to-container-create-by-docker-compose/44682/5).

I also followed the suggestions at https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/275: I can confirm that the MySql root user is linked to any IP (`%`), while the IP address for the service is configured as `*`, which seems another way of representing "any address" like 0.0.0.0.

The relevant log messages I get when starting the composition and my docker compose script follow (`lexminapi` is logging the received environment variables to check the connection string):

```
   lexmin-mysql    | [Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 8.0.13-1.1.8
   lexmin-mysql    | [Entrypoint] Initializing database
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:11.930174Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.13) initializing of server in progress as process 21
   lexminapi_1     | ZAX__CONNECTIONSTRING=Server=lexmin-mysql;Database=zax_master;Uid=root;Pwd=password;SslMode=none
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:22.077828Z 5 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
   lexminapi_1     | Application startup exception: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
   lexminapi_1     |    at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ConnectAsync(ConnectionSettings cs, ILoadBalancer loadBalancer, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ServerSession.cs:line 322
   lexminapi_1     |    at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ConnectionPool.cs:line 112
   lexminapi_1     |    at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ConnectionPool.cs:line 141
   lexminapi_1     |    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.CreateSessionAsync(Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line 405
   lexminapi_1     |    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.OpenAsync(Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line 175
   lexminapi_1     |    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line 161
   lexminapi_1     |    at Zax.MySql.MySqlZaxAdmin.EnsureCatalogExists()
   lexminapi_1     |    at LexminApi.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) in /src/LexminApi/Startup.cs:line 310
   lexminapi_1     | --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   lexminapi_1     |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
   lexminapi_1     |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   lexminapi_1     |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.AutoRequestServicesStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   lexminapi_1     |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
   lexminapi_1     | Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
   lexminapi_1     | MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
   lexminapi_1     |    at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ConnectAsync(ConnectionSettings cs, ILoadBalancer loadBalancer, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ServerSession.cs:line 322
   lexminapi_1     |    at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ConnectionPool.cs:line 112
   lexminapi_1     |    at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ConnectionPool.cs:line 141
   lexminapi_1     |    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.CreateSessionAsync(Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line 405
   lexminapi_1     |    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.OpenAsync(Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line 175
   lexminapi_1     |    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line 161
   lexminapi_1     |    at Zax.MySql.MySqlZaxAdmin.EnsureCatalogExists()
   lexminapi_1     |    at LexminApi.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) in /src/LexminApi/Startup.cs:line 310
   lexminapi_1     | --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   lexminapi_1     |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
   lexminapi_1     |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   lexminapi_1     |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.AutoRequestServicesStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   lexminapi_1     |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
   lexminapi_1     |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   lexminapi_1     |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String shutdownMessage)
   lexminapi_1     |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token)
   lexminapi_1     |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
   lexminapi_1     |    at LexminApi.Program.Main(String[] args) in /src/LexminApi/Program.cs:line 64
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:25.515319Z 5 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'mysql.infoschema@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:25.515408Z 5 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:25.515434Z 5 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:25.515458Z 5 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:25.515505Z 5 [Warning] [MY-010323] [Server] 'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:25.515540Z 5 [Warning] [MY-010323] [Server] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:25.515570Z 5 [Warning] [MY-010311] [Server] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:25.515826Z 5 [Warning] [MY-010330] [Server] 'tables_priv' entry 'user mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:25.515846Z 5 [Warning] [MY-010330] [Server] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:27.343300Z 0 [System] [MY-013170] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.13) initializing of server has completed
   lexmin-mysql    | [Entrypoint] Database initialized
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:30.122415Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.13) starting as process 67
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:31.233579Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:31.270181Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'mysql.infoschema@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:31.270517Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:31.270675Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:31.270818Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:31.271038Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010323] [Server] 'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:31.272659Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010323] [Server] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:31.272734Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010311] [Server] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:31.285399Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010330] [Server] 'tables_priv' entry 'user mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:31.286316Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010330] [Server] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:31.299467Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.13'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:31.474623Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock'
   lexmin-mysql    | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
   lexmin-mysql    | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leapseconds' as time zone. Skipping it.
   lexmin-mysql    | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/tzdata.zi' as time zone. Skipping it.
   lexmin-mysql    | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
   lexmin-mysql    | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:37.721908Z 9 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'healthchecker@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:37.721967Z 9 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'mysql.infoschema@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:37.721997Z 9 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:37.722022Z 9 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:37.722068Z 9 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:37.722135Z 9 [Warning] [MY-010323] [Server] 'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:37.722157Z 9 [Warning] [MY-010323] [Server] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:37.722203Z 9 [Warning] [MY-010311] [Server] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:37.722596Z 9 [Warning] [MY-010330] [Server] 'tables_priv' entry 'user mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:37.722642Z 9 [Warning] [MY-010330] [Server] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 
   lexmin-mysql    | [Entrypoint] ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
   lexmin-mysql    | 
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:37.765710Z 10 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user root. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.13).
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:40.346144Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.13)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
   lexmin-mysql    | [Entrypoint] Server shut down
   lexmin-mysql    | 
   lexmin-mysql    | [Entrypoint] MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.
   lexmin-mysql    | 
   lexmin-mysql    | [Entrypoint] Starting MySQL 8.0.13-1.1.8
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:41.244150Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.13) starting as process 1
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:42.257165Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:42.286105Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'healthchecker@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:42.286148Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'mysql.infoschema@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:42.286179Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:42.286210Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:42.286236Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:42.286296Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010323] [Server] 'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:42.286318Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010323] [Server] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:42.286349Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010311] [Server] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:42.292963Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010330] [Server] 'tables_priv' entry 'user mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:42.293011Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010330] [Server] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:42.303034Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.13'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
   lexmin-mysql    | 2018-11-20T07:59:42.329828Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
   lexminapi_1     | Application is shutting down...
```

Script:

```
   version: '3.4'

   services:
     # MongoDB
     lexmin-mongo:
       image: mongo
       container_name: lexmin-mongo
       environment:
         - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/data/db
         - MONGO_LOG_DIR=/dev/null
       ports:
         - 27017:27017
       command: mongod --smallfiles --logpath=/dev/null # --quiet
       ports:
         - 27017:27017
       networks:
         - lexmin-network

     # MySql
     lexmin-mysql:
       image: mysql/mysql-server
       container_name: lexmin-mysql
       command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
       environment:
         - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
         - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%
       ports:
         - 3306:3306
       networks:
         - lexmin-network

     lexminapi:
       image: XXX:lexminapi
       ports:
         - 34577:80
       depends_on:
         - lexmin-mongo
         - lexmin-mysql
       command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "lexmin-mongo:27017", "--", "dotnet", "LexminApi.dll"]
       environment:
         # for Windows use : as separator, for non Windows use __
         # (see https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/issues/469)
         - ZAX__CONNECTIONSTRING=Server=lexmin-mysql;Database=zax_master;Uid=root;Pwd=password;SslMode=none
       networks:
         - lexmin-network

   networks:
     lexmin-network
```

Comment: Are you able to connect using some mysql client?

Comment: Yes, if I launch MySql Workbench after docker-compose up and connect to localhost with user root@localhost I can successfully connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally seem to have found a solution, involving two changes to the above:

1. it appears that we must use a dictionary rather than an array when configuring MySql environment variables, as found at [connecting to a docker-compose mysql container denies access but docker running same image does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37459031/connecting-to-a-docker-compose-mysql-container-denies-access-but-docker-running/37460872#37460872). So I changed my composer like this:

`environment:
      # the password that will be set for the MySQL root superuser account
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'`

Note that using a dictionary requires putting `%` between quotes, or you will get a YAML error.

2. once changed as above, I got intermittent results: sometimes the app would start, most of the times anyway it still got a connection error. As this pointed at a timeout issue, I googled around for a good retry-pattern and found [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly). I thus wrapped my MySql seed code into a Polly `Execute` method, like this:

`Policy.Handle()
    .WaitAndRetry(new[]
    {
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)
    }, (exception, timeSpan, context) =>
    {
        string message = $"Unable to connect to MySql (sleep {timeSpan}): {exception.Message}";
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }).Execute(() =>
{
  // ... MySql init code here...
});`

Note that the correct place for seeding in ASP.NET Core 2 is *not* `Startup.cs`; see e.g. [How to seed in Entity Framework Core 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45148389/how-to-seed-in-entity-framework-core-2).

When I launch the app, I can now see the first timeout at 10", and then the retry is triggered until the app is launched without exiting because of a `MySqlException`.