# How to create foreign keys to tables generated from enums?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have built a lookup table based on enums, pretty much based on that suggestion:
[How to create a table corresponding to enum in EF6 Code First?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34557574/how-to-create-a-table-corresponding-to-enum-in-ef6-code-first/34558339#34558339)

Now my problem is that I am unable to configure the foreign key for MyEntity.OrderType to the OrderType table.

For more context, these are my types:

```
public enum OrderTypeEnum
{
    Buy = 1, Sell = 2
}

public class OrderType : EntityEnumAdapterBase<OrderTypeEnum>
{
    // this base class implements Id, Name and Description properties as can be seen here:
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34557574/how-to-create-a-table-corresponding-to-enum-in-ef6-code-first/34558339#34558339
}

public partial class MyEntity
{
    [Required]
    public OrderType Type { get; set; } // stored as int using a value conversion
}
```

Now as the database schema for MyEntity is generated, it's lacking the foreign key constraint on `MyEntity.Type` to the `OrdeType.Id`.
**How can I achieve that?**

What I have tried so far, was adding a navigaion property on MyEntity as such:

```
public class OrderType : EntityEnumAdapterBase<OrderTypeEnum>
{
    public IList<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }
}
```

Then configure it as such in `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)`

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
    .HasOne(bc => bc.Type)``
    .WithMany(c => c.MyEntities)
    .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.TypeId);
```

This fails with messsage: *'Type' cannot be used as a property on entity type 'MyEntity' because it is configured as a navigation.*

So, how do I tackle adding FK constraints to tables generated from enums? The mentioned approach also seems a bit verbose, as I had to add `MyEntity.TypeId` (of type int) and OrderType.MyEntities.

Ideally on `MyEntity` I even wouldn't want to have `OrderType`, but rather `OrderTypeEnum` instead as such:

```
public partial class MyEntity
{
    [Required]
    public OrderTypeEnum Type { get; set; } // stored as int using a value conversion
}
```

Comment: *'Type' cannot be used as a property on entity type 'MyEntity' because it is configured as a navigation* This is *not* coming from the shown fluent configuration. What concerns me is the comment *stored as int using a value conversion*, so check for fluent configuration using something like `modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property(e => e.Type)`. Reference property in this case represents FK navigation property and should store the Id, hence should not use value conversion. And in general the message is telling you that `Property` method cannot be used with navigation properties.

Comment: This is the conversion and only appearance of  `modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property(e => e.Type)`:

`modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property(p => p.Type).HasConversion(new EnumToNumberConverter<OrderTypeEnum, int>());`

Do I need to get away from that?

Comment: Indeed. I guess it was needed when the property type was `OrderTypeEnum`, but with the new design it's incorrect, causing the exception and should be removed.

Comment: Oh, great, that actually worked, thanks @IvanStoev 
If you post this as an answer, I will accept it.

BTW, do you know what are my chances of getting rid of OrderType.MyEntities list, that I need only in the `.WithMany(c => c.MyEntities)` part?